# Can a green wire be used as hot if it's reidentified?

Tags: wiring

Say you have a whip with red, black, green, and white wires. Three hot conductors are needed. Does it satisfy national code if you use the green wire as a hot connection and label both ends as "HOT" using electrical tape?

Comment: Is this "whip" a flexible *conduit* with conductors in it, or a flexible *cable*?

Comment: Flexible conduit.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not, for 2 reasons.

- **You need the ground for ground!**  That metallic jacket is NOT a suitable ground, *that's why there's a ground **wire***.
- You are not allowed to re-mark wires that are smaller than 4 AWG (which is huge) with the solitary exception of "marking white to a hot *if* it's in cable".

What you should do is instead, run flexible metallic conduit (FMC) and run the individual THHN wires that you need for your application.

Answer (score 4):

### No, it doesn't

NEC 250.119 prohibits *any* green, green/yellow striped, or bare wire from being used as a hot, save for a couple of exceptions that have to do with green SPT-2 cordage and the use of green hot conductors to feed the greens on traffic signal heads.

### However, there likely is a way out

Since your whip is based on flexible *conduit*, though, there should be plenty of room inside there for another THHN of the appropriate gauge.  As a result, you can simply install the whip and then pull a blue (or whatever color other than green, white, or grey) THHN wire through it to add that extra hot conductor.